# how to change print in the end of the function for return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I found a sudoku solver code however, I need the function to return the grid instead of printing it. Any idea how?

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
        [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
        [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
        [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
        [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
        [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
        [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
        [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0]
            ]

def checker(y,x,n):
    global grid
    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[y][i] == n:
            return False
    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[i][x] == n:
            return False
    x0 = (x//3)*3
    y0 = (y//3)*3
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if grid[y0+i][x0+j] == n:
                return False
    return True

def solver(grid):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if checker(y,x,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solver(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))
    input("More?")

solver(grid)
```

This function does give you the correct solution however, I would like to call this function in my other project but I am not able to as the output is a print and not the grid itself.

Thanks!

Comment: how about changing the `print` to `return`? (and removing the paranthesis...)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what the issue is here.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I already tried that. The output would be "None" if i use `return grid` instead of `print(np.matrix(grid))` @Tomerikoo

Comment: @AMC I need this function to return the grid instead of printing it.

Comment: @AdrianHeldes By the way you shouldn’t be using `numpy.matrix`, it might even be removed entirely at some point in the future.

Comment: Can’t you already access `grid` in other functions anyway?

Comment: What do you mean *output would be "None*? If you remove the `print` there is no output to your program...

Comment: @AMC I can access the grid but only the initial one. When I run the function and then `print(grid)` I get the initial grid I created.

Comment: @Tomerikoo there is another `return` in one of my for loops. 
`for n in range(1,10):
                    if checker(y,x,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solver(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return`
this should return "None" if there is no solution to the sudoku

Comment: @AdrianHeldes Both the variable and the parameter to `solver` share the same name, by the way, that might cause some problems.

Comment: @Tomerikoo this is the whole code. If I use `return grid` instead of `print(grid)` the output is "None" because there is one more `return` before calling `return grid`.

Comment: So either there is no solution, or you have a bug... An empty `return` returns `None` so I don't understand why you are surprised for getting it as the output. I recommend doing some basic debugging on your code like using a debugger or adding some prints or using [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: @AMC I will try using different variables

Comment: @Tomerikoo but why does it give me a solution when I use print but does not give me any when I return the grid instead of printing it?

Comment: Because the first call will probably get inside the `if` and eventually you will be returned with `None`. The grid itself is only returned by the **last** recursive call

Comment: I'm trying to refactor the code to get rid of the global variable, but I'm struggling to understand it, so you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the fact that I call the function inside the function. So basically it solves the sudoku until there is not solution. As there is not solution the grid did not change so if I `return grid` it shows the original grid due to the fact that it already went through all the possible solutions. So I need to somehow stop the function after finding first solution.

Answer (score 0):

On "def solver" function change print to return. Then call the function like , a=solver(grid) so the returned value is stored in the a variable.

Comment: If you do so then the output is "None".
`return grid`

`a = solver(grid)`

`print(a)`

Comment: Then that means that the print there is not printing anything , am i wrong ?

Comment: Or maybe u did it so the first return interrupted and ofc u got a none

Comment: Indeed it does print nothing because there is one more return that returns nothing if there is not solution. This function goes through all possibilities and works when using print.